# update UITableViewCell when UICollectionViewCell is selected

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am creating a project where I have a lot of options for user to select among different plans.

So I created a UITableViewCell, put UICollectionView inside with one UICollectionViewCell as one plan.

Now user can select only one plan out of all.

Let's say the user selects the second plan, I need to update the price on a button which is in UITableViewCell.

I know we can reload tableCell and update. But is there any other way to do except reloading UITableViewCell

[image: UI for that cell]

Let me know the best way to do that except reloading whole tableviewcell

Comment: You dont need to reload the cell to update the label, write a delegate between your hosting tableView cell and colectionView. When user selects a cell in UICollectionViewCell simply send that data to hosting tableView cell using delegate and update the price label. That should do the job. Similar use case is showing progress bar in each cell, you dont reload each cell every time you have to update progress amount in progress bar rather u update progress bar instance progress amount. I know out of context example but makes sense to quote in this scenario I believe

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Can you share how to do that?

Comment: Whats the issue buddy ? Isn't it straight forward ? You want me to post a code for protocol ? If thats the case Ill post the link to one of my earlier answered question

Comment: @SandeepBhandari yeah give me the link. I am kind of confused

Comment: Finding it difficult to search one so gimme a minute lemme post the answer afresh

Answer (score 0):

In didselect method of Uicollectionview, get the tableviewcell of price displaying and update the button.

```
 CollectionView didSelectItem method  
 {  

NSIndexPath *indexpathoftableviewcell = [NSIndexPath indexpathForRow:1 inSection:0];   
UITableViewCell *priceCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexpathoftableviewcell];       
UIButton *priceBtn = (UIButton*)[priceCell viewWithTag:tagOfBtn];
[priceBtn setTitle:@"43432" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `UITableViewCell` loads the `UICollectionView` inside it, so the obvious choice for UICollectionView's DataSource and Delegate should be your UICollectionViewCell.

So in your TableView Cell you can simply access the label that you need to update with price as shown below

```
extension MyTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let someCell : MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "your_identifier", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        return someCell
    }
}

extension MyTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        self.priceLabel.text = "\(cell.value)"
    }
}
```

here I am assuming that your `CollectionViewCell` is a custom cell and has a property named `value` where it store the price of plan

Answer (score 0):

Accommodate the **Plans (UICollectionView)** & **Price (UILabel or UIButton)** in the UITableViewCell rather than making it as separate cells

Here is the reason behind it.

**Both** **Price** and **Plans** are tightly coupled. It means, When you change **plan** the respective **price** should come and this requirement may grow in future like adding some more views. If you accommodate the entire part in one UITableViewCell, it will become very easy. **This way you can manage your design future proof.**

regarding the question, **the price is just like one more IBOutlet in the CustomTableViewCell**. Just update the price in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}
```